# Python3 extract multiple subtrings

Tags: python-3.x, string

I have the following git diff available, gained via the api:

```
+cookbook 'foo', git: 'https://XXXXX', tag: '1.5.44' 
+cookbook 'bar', git: 'https://XXXXX', tag: '1.2.1'
```

Now i need to extract foo and 1.5.44 as well as bar and 1.2.1.

Tried it in several ways (re, split, find) but couldn't get it to work.

The overall goal is to create two lists. One containing the git repos, one containing the tags,
and than build a dict using zip method.

Comment: Please post the code you tried so we can help you fix it. [edit] the question and add a [mre]. Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: He Patrick, i was in hurry, you're right. That's not the way questions should be asked here. But Rakesh posted the right regex, so it's solved. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Regex:

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = """+cookbook 'foo', git: 'https://XXXXX', tag: '1.5.44' +cookbook 'bar', git: 'https://XXXXX', tag: '1.2.1'"""

print(re.findall(r"\+\w+\s+'(.*?)'", s))  # -->['foo', 'bar']
print(re.findall(r"tag: '(.*?)'", s))     # -->['1.5.44', '1.2.1']
```